# IntellIj Indexer takes too long. Any alternative?

Tags: java, search, intellij-idea

I've used IntellIJ 9 thru 12 Ultimate, but always surprised how long it takes to search (Ctrl-Shft-F). If the files are Indexed, shouldn't it be quick (under 2 seconds)? 
Either I don't have my IntelliJ settings right or Indexing simply does not provide this feature.

I've searched JetBrains PlugIn Repository and was unable to find a viable plugin.
There are "Search and Replace" plugins but that's not what I'm referring to.
There are "Navigation" but also not the same thing.

Is anyone aware of a way to index projects and search within IntelliJ ?
A sample could be "find the string 'module' anywhere in the project".
Today, I think that takes too long in my opinion, approx. 30-45 seconds.
Long enough to distract me and forget why I was searching for that.

Comment: What's the size of your project in megabytes, how many files?

Comment: This particular project has 40,000 files and results in >800MB. Is that reaching an upper limit for IntelliJ searching?

Answer (score 1):

That's strange. Try to invalidate cache in your project.
Next step I could suggest is to check your HDD performance.
Moving your project on SSD should improve your speed.

Also if project is quite large try to increase memory for intelliJ.

Comment: I've not had the pleasure of working with SSD are work, but I'm sure its faster. Invalidating caches for me also results in clearing the Run/Debug configurations that I've so meticulously setup so always hesitant to do that unless its a last resort.

Comment: this configs will be cleared because you haven't saved them. Save them, then it would be ok.

Answer (score 1):

Please check "whole words only" option when searching. Only if it's on, IDEA is using index.

Comment: Yes, this is indeed faster and could come in handy for my ADD. =) Still curious why this 'index' is not as fast as Lucene, Attivio or OpenGrok searches. Those return in less and a second. I would be more than happy to wait 30 mins to index on initial project import to obtain sub-second searches. But maybe, thats just me.

Comment: An interesting observation. Maybe because Lucene is optimized for text searching, and IDEA's index for more kinds of searching and as little as possible storage space on disk. Maybe we'll optimize this in future :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to reload your project once after you change your build settings. IntelliJ indexes the jars for every change in the build of the project(you can configure them as well).

try to reload IntelliJ by closing and reopening to index it faster.

Every time I change the POM dependencies, I will reload it to make it faster. I'm using community edition.